# how to fix error in django addition url path not find not link to new code

Tags: python, django

My url path finder doeds not find result.html page when i click on submit button it will not find that result.html page . it can not find the second url path.Iam trying to add two numbers in Django a basic django Programmge in first it will open the home.html page then on click submit it will not open the result.html page on which the result is displaed

i have tried to import pattrens but it will show errors pattrens can not be imported somethig like i have also tried to direct the page from

### This is my url.py file

```
from django.conf.urls import  include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns =  [

    url('', views.home,name='home'),
    url(r'^add/', views.add, name ='add'),


]

 ##this is my home.html file


{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}


<body>
<h1> Hello {{name}} !!!!!!! </h1>

<form  action="add">
  Enter First Number : <input type="text" name ="first">
  Enter Second Number : <input type="text" name ="second">
 <input type ="submit">        

</form>

</body>    

## this is my view.py file

from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.


def home(request):
    return render(request,'home.html',{'name': 'Harsh'})

def add(request):
    val1= int(request.GET['first'])
    val2= int(request.GET['second'])

    res = val1 + val2

    return render(request,'result.html',{'result':res}) 

## this is my result.html file 


{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

Result : {{result}}


{% endblock %}


#this is base .html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Tisraa</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="cyan">

    {% block content %}

    {% endblock %}
```

i did't understand where the proble is because when i rub or erase  the
first url code that is     url('', views.home,name='home'),
it will show the result page but it will not coonect when i push the submit button`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

Change your url of `home` to:

```
url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
```

otherwise all cases will be handled by home.
Or move your `add` url above to make `django` see it first. Sequence of urls matters in django.

```
url(r'^add/', views.add, name ='add'),
url('', views.home,name='home'),
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps the `/` is causing the issue

try this:

```
<form  action="add/">
```

and the url is missing the beginning/end regex

```
url('^$', views.home,name='home'),
```